# Particular solution and complex roots in second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''+y=\cos(x)$$

If the equation has the form: $ay''+by'+cy=\cos(kx)$ then
the particular solution has the form: $y_p(x)=x^h[A\cos(kx)+B\sin(kx)]$, where $h$ is the degree of multiplicity of $k$ as a root of the homogenous equation.

The homogenous equation has complex roots $\pm i$. Since in my equation $k=1$ the degree of multiplicity of $k$ is zero, since $1\neq \pm i$, therefore the solution has form $x^0[A\cos(kx)+B\sin(kx)]$. But plugging my equation in symbolab tells me that this equation's particular solution has the form of $x^1[A\cos(kx)+B\sin(kx)]$ so it implies that $k$ is one of the roots of the equation.

What I'm getting wrong here?

Comment: This is the correct expression I just want to understand why the $x$, if 1 isn't the root of the characteristic equation... EDIT: problem solved. Actually I have to check the degree of multiplicity of the element $ik$ as root of the characteristic equation. Since $ik=i$ and $i$ is one root, the degree of multiplicity is 1, therefore we need $x^1$ multiplying the rest of the expression for $y_p(x)$. Explanation just for future reference if anyones tumbles across the same issue.

Comment: Maybe you can put this explanation in the form of an answer.